# Joining multiple files into a single file in unix

Tags: file, unix, mainframe, cat

I have two types of files - a simple character file and a pdf file.

Name of first file is plainFile.abc and name of second file is pdfFile.pdf

I want to join the two files into a single file.

The name of the destination file would be combined.file

I am using cat command to achieve the same:

```
Way 1:

cat plainFile.abc > combined.file
cat pdfFile.pdf > combined.file

Way 2:

cat plainFile.abc > combined.file
cat pdfFile.pdf >> combined.file
```

Notice the difference in '>' and '>>' in above ways.

In way one,  the second file is not getting appended to the destination file even though the definition says 'The operator > can be used to combine multiple files into one.'

In way two, both files get combined, however the second file is getting appended in the position where first file ends. I do not want this. I want the second file to start from a new position in a new line.

The idea is to send the destination file over to mainframes where it will be parsed.

So I want the second file to start from position one:

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
second file should start from position one
```

However, right now if the first file is ending at position 3 then second file is getting appended right after that i.e. at position 4.

How to achieve my requirement?

Is there a better way then CAT command?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You want to combine 2 files but have them take up the same positions in the file? Oh, you want it to just start at the beginning of a new line?

Comment: @Jon Lin: 2nd One. I want the new file to start at the beginning of a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the new file to start at the beginning of a new line.

If this is what you want, `cat` is probably the command you want. You can insert a newline by either piping a blank echo:

```
cat plainFile.abc > combined.file
echo >> combined.file
cat pdfFile.pdf >> combined.file
```

Or, a slightly less messy way, you can create a file with just a blank line using echo:

```
echo > blank_line
```

Then use this cat command:

```
cat plainFile.abc blank_line pdfFile.pdf > combined.file
```

---

## EDIT

> 1) The pdf is not starting from a new line. 2) Also, the pdf is shown as damaged file in mainframe. Is CAT the correct way to combine multiple files of different type into single file ?

If you want to **[concatenate them](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/concatenate.html)**, then yes, you use `cat`. If you want to combine many files together and then be able to separate them afterwards, you **don't** use cat because that's not what it's for. The binary pdf is going to be corrupted because you've concatenated it to the end of an ascii file. If you want to be able to separate the files later, follow infgeoax's advice and use `tar`.

`cat` doesn't do things that allow you to separate what you've concatenated together once you've done it. For example, you have 3 strings: "are", "a", "dyes". You concatenate them and you get "areadyes". Without any prior knowledge to what you started with, you can't separate them into 3 strings again. Is it "are", "a", "dyes"? Or "a", "read", "yes"? You can add spaces, or some other character for delimiting your strings but what if the string you've started with has one of those characters?

If you don't have `tar` on this mainframe, you'll have to think of something else. Maybe instead of using `cat` on the pdf file, use something like `hexdump`, `od`, or `uuencode`/`uudecode` to dump the binary file to ascii, then on the mainframe, rebuild the binary file.

Comment: 1) The pdf is not starting from a new line. 2) Also, the pdf is shown as damaged file in mainframe. Is CAT the correct way to combine multiple files of different type into single file ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `tar`.

```
tar cf outputfile plainfile.abc pdfFile.pdf
```

And on the mainframe, you can reverse the process

```
tar xf ouputfile
```